# How to create label and dynamically add binding to its content property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a label at runtime and connect it's `Content` property to another `TextBox` control which is in my `UserControl` called `MyLabelSettings`.

This is what I got so far:

```
Label currCtrl = new Label();
MyLabelSettings currCtrlProperties = new MyLabelSettings();

// Bindings to properties
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = currCtrlProperties.textBox_Text.Text;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Label.VisibilityProperty);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(currCtrl.Content, Label.ContentProperty, binding);
```

The last row shows an error which I did not figure out how to solve:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations. SetBinding(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.Data.BindingBase)' has some invalid arguments

I have in `MyLabelSettings` the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`
which has the following code when the `TexBox.Text` changes

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextChanged"));
}
```

Is there a better way to bind these 2? Or am I doing something wrong in this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simpler than you realize:

This:

```
binding.Source = currCtrlProperties.textBox_Text.Text;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Label.VisibilityProperty);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(currCtrl.Content, Label.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Should be this:

```
//The source must be an object, NOT a property
binding.Source = currCtrlProperties;
//Since the binding source is not a DependencyObject, we using string to find it's property
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("TextToBind");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(currCtrl, Label.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Before, you were attempting to bind the value to an object's property via a property. Now, you're binding the value to an object's property via an object (:

Notes:

- You are attempting to bind the text of a control that exists in an instance of a class you just made.

  ```
  MyLabelSettings currCtrlProperties = new MyLabelSettings();
  ```

  I base this assumption off this line:

  ```
  currCtrlProperties.textBox_Text.Text;
  ```

  Which appears to contain a text control of some sort. Rather, you want bind the text of a **property** that exists in an instance of a class you make, not a **control**.